# Jquery dynamic link removal

Tags: jquery, html, image, hyperlink

Consider the following

```
var newLink = $('<a/>').attr('href', name);
previewImage.wrap(newLink);
```

It outputs

```
<a href><img src=" "/></a>
```

I need some Jquery code to modify this to:
`<img src=" "/>` (Only remove the wrapping link without the img). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```
theImage.unwrap();
```

E.g.:

```
newLink.find("img").unwrap();
```